# Finding solutions to row reduced matrix python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a reduced Matrix in this form:

```
   x    y    z    =
[[2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0], 
 [0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

And I want an array containing the solutions.

In this case I'd want to return

```
  z    y     x
[1.0, 0.5, -1.0]
```

We can assume it is a perfect triangle with no free variables.

I was looking at `scipy.linalg.solve` to solve, but it requires the form `Ax=B` and I'm not sure how to convert to this form.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "solutions"?

Comment: See edit. I want return x,y,z in this case, in the form of an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have all of the information you need to use `numpy.linalg.solve`. `A` is represented by the first 3 columns of your 2d array, and `b` is the last column. Hence if you slice your array into those elements respectively, you can call `.solve`. Note that I sliced off the last row such that your system becomes well-determined, as `numpy.linalg.solve` requires a well-determined system:

```
init_array = numpy.array(
        [[2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
         [0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0],
         [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

A = init_array[0:3,:-1]
b = init_array[0:3, -1]
x = numpy.linalg.solve(A, b)
print(x)
```

**Outputs:**

```
[-1.   0.5  1. ]
```

---

Further reading:

- [General form of a system of equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#General_form) (Wiki)

Comment: Suppose it was a `nxn` matrix. Would I use `init_array[0:n-1, :-1]`

Comment: @GregPeckory No, you could use list comprehensions to create `A` and `b` however. For instance `A = [sub[:3] for sub in coeff[:-1]]`

Comment: Sorry the list comprehension confuses me a bit, could you explain how I might create a general case for `nxn` matrices, sorry for the hassle

Comment: Either convert them to `numpy.array` and then do the slicing, or replace my slicing with `n` for an `n x n` matrix.

Comment: So `A = [sub[:n] for sub in init_array[:-1]]` and what about `b`?

Comment: `b = [sub[-1] for sub in init_array[:-1]]`, although we're really starting to deviate from your original question here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Remark than :

```
     [2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]  x     0
     [0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]  y  =  0
     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]  z     0
     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,-1.0]  t     1
```

has the same solution, with t=-1.

So let `I=np.eye(4)`and  `b=I[3]`. the solution is then given by :

```
In [2]: solve(A-I*b,b)[:-1]
Out[2]: array([-1. ,  0.5,  1. ])
```